# ArcMap Spatial Analyst - Kernel Density Estimation Produces Blank Rasters

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, spatial-analyst, kernel-density

My problem is with the Kernel Density operation in Spatial Analyst. ArcMap produces blank rasters for some reason when given a normal point feature class as input. [image: Inputs for Kernel Density Estimation]I had no problem creating the heatmap I wanted in QGIS and then adding the raster back into Arc, but would like to avoid this inefficient process in the future. My inputs are attached. The same happens with the Point Density operation. Any ideas?

I have ensured all layers are the same projection as the data frame.

Comment: What are the units of the coordinates in which your data are physically stored?  Was a default "search radius" value supplied?  If so, what was it?

Comment: Thanks @whuber, of course, they are for optional weighting, Its been a while since I used it-I deleted the answer. Regarding OP's problem, it might be a scaling issue, try calculating the kernel density with the default cell size first to see if you are  giving it a resolution smaller than required to fit a continuous surface over your area.

Answer (score 5):

If you are performing calculations on a Geographic Coordinate System instead of a Projected Coordinate System, you will get blank data returned.  Reproject the data into a Projected Coordinate System and try it again.

See: [Problem:  The Kernel Density tool does not generate the expected output in ArcMap](http://support.esri.com/ja/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/43511)

> The issue occurs because the projection of the data is in a geographic
>   coordinate system (GCS). To use the tool, the data must be in a
>   projected coordinate system (PCS) that has a linear unit of
>   measurement because the tool calculates the number of features per
>   unit area.